# how to perform drill through using R language

Tags: r

I have a sample text  as  "Click Here" when i hit on that text it has to take me to the another page for example as of now say "www.google.com" how to avail this using R language. Which libraries has to be added to perform this.

I have used

```
library("grid")
library("lattice", lib.loc="C:/Program Files/R/R-3.2.2/library")
library("ggplot2", lib.loc="~/R/win-library/3.2")

topvp <- viewport(y=1, just="top", name="topvp",height=unit(1, "lines"))
botvp <- viewport(y=0, just="bottom", name="botvp",height=unit(1, "npc") - unit(1, "lines"))
grid.rect(gp=gpar(fill="grey"), vp=topvp, name="toprect")
grid.rect(vp=botvp, name="botrect")


library("gridSVG")

widthValues <- unit(c(1, 1), c("npc", "in"))

widthvalues

grid.animate("toprect", width=widthValues, duration=3)
grid.animate("botrect", width=widthValues, duration=3)


gridToSVG("gridanim.svg")#not connecting shown with an error message
grid.export("gridanim.svg")

grid.text("Click Here", vp=topvp, name="hypertext")
grid.hyperlink("hypertext", "http://www.google.com")
```

it is creating rectangle and performing animation but when I hit on Click Here text it is not taking me to Google page nor showing hand symbol.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You need a better title for this.

Comment: Looking at this code and your self-answer it appeared that you just committed these actions out of order. This would seem to warrant embarrassment on your part and deletion of the question. Voting to close as too simple to warrant SO space.

Answer (score 0):

Perform these steps 
Step 1: Add library files

```
library("grid")
library("gridSVG")
```

Step 2: Execute these lines

```
grid.text("Click Here", vp=topvp, name="hypertext")
grid.hyperlink("hypertext", "http://www.google.com")
```

Step 3: Save the file by default it gets stored in documents or specify to the folder where you would like to save.

```
gridToSVG("gridhyper.svg")
```

Step 4: Open the file in google chrome or firefox to see the output with action